# For two sinusoidal waves, what does the magnitude of their coherence tell us, and why do the periodogram and csd commands yield incorrect results?

Tags: power-spectral-density, coherence

Suppose I have 2 seconds of data sampled at 1000 Hz., and two sinusoids differing only in amplitude and phase shift:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import csd,periodogram

t = np.arange(0, 2, 0.001);
x = np.sin(2*np.pi*200*t)
y = 3*np.sin(2*np.pi*200*(t-np.pi/2))
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.cohere(x, y)
```

The resulting plot of coherence is shown below.

[image]

Q1: Am I correct that the coherence is identically equal to one throughout and that the frequency axis is really going from 0 to 500 Hz, the Nyquist frequency?

Q2: For simple sinusoids, does a coherence identically equal to one mean they essentially differ in amplitude and have identical frequencies and a fixed phase difference?

Now I tried to compute the coherence using the cross-spectral density of x and y, along with their respective power spectral densities:

```
f,Pxx=periodogram(x)
f,Pyy=periodogram(y)
f,Pxy=csd(x,y)

Coh=np.zeros(len(f))
for i in range(len(f)):
    Coh[i]=abs(Pxy[i])**2/(Pxx[i]*Pyy[i])

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(f,Coh)
```

This resulted in the graph below.

Q3: Shouldn't the graphs be identical? What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect it's something different between `csd` and `periodogram`. If, instead, I use `csd` for all calculations:

```
f,Pxx=csd(x , x )
f,Pyy=csd(y , y)
f,Pxy=csd(x , y)

Coh=np.zeros(len(f))
for i in range(len(f)):
    Coh[i]=abs(Pxy[i])**2/(abs(Pxx[i]*Pyy[i]))

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(f,Coh)
```

then I get the figure below, which seems much closer to what you're expecting to see.

[image: Coherence calculated using csd only]

`periodogram` probably uses some averaging which doesn't help in the coherence calculation. By default, [it looks like `csd` uses no averaging](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.8.0/scipy/signal/_spectral_py.py#L156-L286), but when called to calculate `periodogram` it uses averaging.

Comment: Ah!  That's very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do here is ill defined. At most frequencies $P_{xx}$, $P_{yy}$ and $P_{xy}$ are essentially zero, so the coherence is mostly $\frac{0}{0}$ which is undefined.

What happens in the actual code is highly dependent on how exactly the estimators are implemented (spectral leakage, windowing, hop size, scaling, etc) and good old fashioned numerical noise.

In your second graph, your Y-axis scale appears to be $10^{56}$ which is a strong indicator of some serious numerical problem.

Answer (score 0):

As Peter indicated there is a difference between `csd` and `periodogram`.  However, from his answer it was not clear when and why are averages used. So I will expand on that.

Note that periodogram uses Welch with a hardcoded `noverlap=`0 and a default `window='boxcar'`. As can be seen in the last portion of the function source code

```
return welch(x, fs=fs, window=window, nperseg=nperseg, noverlap=0,
             nfft=nfft, detrend=detrend, return_onesided=return_onesided,
             scaling=scaling, axis=axis)
```

In turn, `Welch` function internally uses `csd` of the input with itself, `window='hann'` and `noverlap=None` (which translates to a 50% segment overlap) as can be seen in the last portion of the function source code

```
freqs, Pxx = csd(x, x, fs=fs, window=window, nperseg=nperseg,
                 noverlap=noverlap, nfft=nfft, detrend=detrend,
                 return_onesided=return_onesided, scaling=scaling,
                 axis=axis, average=average)
```

Finally `CSD` uses `_spectral_helper` internal function.

It is easy to see that both `CSD` and `periodogram` end up calling this same function. The difference is that they call it with different input arguments.

Besides the differences already explained above, they key difference is that `CSD` calls `_spectral_helper` with `nperseg=None`, which means `_spectral_helper` defaults to nperseg=256 samples, computing a few averages because your input has 2000 samples. On the other hand `periodogram` calls `_spectral_helper` with `nperseg=2000` and no averages are computed.

In other words if you compute the code below your are doing exactly the same as if you were calling periodogram

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import csd,periodogram

t = np.arange(0, 2, 0.001)
x = np.sin(2*np.pi*200*t)
y = 3*np.sin(2*np.pi*200*(t-np.pi/2))
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.cohere(x, y)

f,Pxx=csd(x , x, window='boxcar',noverlap=0,nperseg=len(x))
f,Pyy=csd(y , y, window='boxcar',noverlap=0,nperseg=len(y))
# f,Pxx=periodogram(x)
# f,Pyy=periodogram(y)
f,Pxy=csd(x , y, window='boxcar',noverlap=0)

Coh=np.zeros(len(f))
for i in range(len(f)):
    Coh[i]=abs(Pxy[i])**2/(abs(Pxx[i]*Pyy[i]))

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(f,Coh)
plt.show()
```

But there is no way to call `periodogram` to obtain the same results as in the default `CSD` because the inputs required to do this were hardcoded and you don't have the option to change them